# How to convert unsigned long long value to a string in qt

Tags: qt, label

I have a calulation that returns large value of factorials of a given number  (ex: Factorial of  22  =  17196083355034583040). I want to set the result to a label. I did as shown below.

```
void Dialog::onNumberChanged(unsigned long long Number)
{
    ui->resultPrime->setText(QString::number(Number));
}
```

**MyThread.h**

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);

    void run();
    bool Stop;
    int inputNumber;
    unsigned long long resultFactorial;
    void Resume();
    void Pause();
    bool pause;

private:
    QMutex sync;
    QWaitCondition pauseCond;
//    bool pause;


signals:
    void NumberChanged(unsigned long long);
public slots:

};
```

MyThread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>

MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent):QThread(parent)
{
    pause = false;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    QMutex mutex;
    int n = inputNumber;
        unsigned long long factorial = 1;

//        qDebug() << "Enter a positive integer: ";
//        cin >> n;

        mutex.lock();
        if (n < 0)
            qDebug() << "Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.";
        else {

            for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {

                sync.lock();
                if(pause)
                   pauseCond.wait(&sync); // in this place, your thread will stop to execute until someone calls resume
                qDebug() << "Paused for now" << pause;
                sync.unlock();
                factorial *= i;
                MyThread().msleep(1000);
                emit NumberChanged(factorial);
            }
            qDebug() << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial;
        }

        resultFactorial = factorial;
        mutex.unlock();
//        return factorial;


}

void MyThread::Resume()
{
    sync.lock();
    pause = false;
    sync.unlock();
    pauseCond.wakeAll();
}



void MyThread::Pause()
{
        sync.lock();
        pause = true;
        sync.unlock();
}
```

Dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "mythread.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Dialog; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();
    MyThread *mThread;


private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

public slots:
    void onNumberChanged(unsigned long long);

private slots:
    void on_startPrime_clicked();
    void on_suspendPrime_clicked();
    void on_resumePrime_clicked();
    void on_stopPrime_clicked();
};
#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QDebug>


//bool pauseCondition = false;
int statusOfPrimeThread = 0;
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mThread = new MyThread(this);
    connect(mThread, SIGNAL(NumberChanged(long)), this, SLOT(onNumberChanged(long)));

        ui->activeStatePrime->setText(QString("Not Started"));

//    connect(this, SIGNAL(on_resumePrime_clicked), mThread, SLOT(Resume()));
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::onNumberChanged(unsigned long long Number)
{

    qDebug() << QString::number(17196083355034583040ull);
    ui->resultPrime->setText(QString::number(Number));

}


void Dialog::on_startPrime_clicked()
{
//    Started
    mThread->inputNumber = ui->lineEditPrime->text().toInt();
    mThread->start();
    if(mThread->isRunning()){
        ui->activeStatePrime->setText(QString("Started"));
    }
    qDebug() << QString::number(17196083355034583040ull);

}

void Dialog::on_suspendPrime_clicked()
{
    //Stopped
//    mThread->terminate();
//    pauseCondition = true;
//    mThread->pause = pauseCondition;
    mThread->Pause();
    ui->activeStatePrime->setText(QString("Paused"));

}

void Dialog::on_resumePrime_clicked()
{
   mThread->Resume();

       ui->activeStatePrime->setText(QString("Resumed"));

}

void Dialog::on_stopPrime_clicked()
{
    mThread->terminate();
    ui->activeStatePrime->setText(QString("Terminated"));
}
```

But the label is not changed. How can I set such a large value, and I am correctly using unsigned long long datatype or is there any other datatype that can be used.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting `QString` with `qDebug` output or similar?  You should really provide a [mcve].  `QString::number(17196083355034583040ull)` works as expected for me (Qt5.15.2).

Comment: qDebug() << QString::number(17196083355034583040ull); does not show any output when i use it in the slot  onNumberChanged in Dialog.cpp

Comment: Are you sure `Dialog::onNumberChanged` is actually being called?  Also note that your `connect` call will result in a direct connection as the emitter and receiver both have the same thread affinity.  That means you are updating the GUI from a secondary thread which is not supported.

Comment: Yes, now it works, THANKS